# Salvar somente se não for null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Como eu faço para mapear com Hibernate `@OneToOne` e salvar somente se a informação tiver dados na tabela relacionada?

Exemplo:

```
public class ObservacaoPessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    public Integer PessoaId;
    public String TextoObservacao;

}

public class Pessoas {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    public String Nome;

    public ObservacaoPessoa Obs;

}
```

Quero fazer `Pessoas.Save` mas somente gravar o `Obs` se tiver sido informado algum valor.

Comment: Acredito que este tratamento deve ser feito na hora de salvar a entidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer é o [`optional = true`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#optional--) no `@OneToOne`.

Além disso, o relacionamento inverso (pois ele é bidirecional) pode ser feito com o [`mappedBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#mappedBy--):

```
public class ObservacaoPessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "obs")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    private String textoObservacao;

}
```

```
public class Pessoas {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String nome;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ObservacaoPessoa obs;

}
```

Outras coisas que noto é que os campos devem ser privados. Não use campos públicos, isso é uma má prática de programação.

Para inserir uma entidade, você faria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
Pessoa p = ...;
ObservacaoPessoa obs = ...;
if (obs != null) {
    p.setObs(obs);
    obs.setPessoa(p);
}
em.persist(p);
```

Enfim, para fazer o mapeamento bidirecional funcionar, você deve setar manualmente os dois lados da relação como faria com quaisquer outros dois objetos Java que precisassem se referenciar ciclicamente.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!